# Dishwasher Miele G 898, short cycling

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

all:
I have a Miele G898 SCI Plus, ca.2000 new.  It appears to fill and drain normally, and the circulator pump runs to start with, but very soon it goes into a loop of 15 seconds on, 15 seconds off; eventually the "Water Intake" light comes on and the timer goes to zero, all stop.  I have cleared the filter and sump, even used a wet vac on it.  I did the "does it fill 4 corner glasses while running" test and it fills them in 1 min of total circulating time or less. I think that result means the circulator pump and impeller are OK.

I rebooted the "electronic" more than once, disconnected it from power for hours, and have checked the fault memory, which always shows F00.  My wife wants it gone.  Save me, please.

Comment: obey your wife ..she is tired of the 23 years old machine